# cannot send the email while attaching the excel sheet in php

Tags: php, phpmailer

When i am trying to send an excel sheet as attachment in php, it shows that cannot access the file. But if i am commenting the attachment part, the mail will send perfectly. When i am trying to download the sheet it works perfectly.
Will anyone guide me how can i fix this problem?
Thank you

```
$select="select * from tablename";
$export = mysql_query($select);
$fields = mysql_num_fields($export);
$csv_output = '';
$data='';
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $csv_output .= mysql_field_name($export, $i) . "\t";
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($export)) {
    $line = '';
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        if ((!isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {
            $value = "NULL\t";
        } else {
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim($line) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username ='xxxx@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->setFrom('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'name');
    $mail->addAddress('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'name');
    $mail->addAttachment($csv_output . "\n" . $data);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Report';
    $mail->Body = '<b>Please find the attachment of the  Report</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Please find the attachement of the  Report';
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`addAttachment` expects a path to a file, not raw attachment content. Easiest fix would be to store your attachment content to a temporary file and then give the path to that.

So instead of:

```
$mail->addAttachment($csv_output . "\n" . $data);
```

You could do something like:

```
$report_filename = date('Y-m-d-his-').'-report.txt';
file_put_contents($report_filename, $csv_output . "\n" . $data);
$mail->addAttachment($report_filename);
//....
$mail->send();
unlink($report_filename);
```

Comment: @user12285906 Excellent, I'm happy to hear that!

Comment: user12285906, please mark this as your accepted answer so that @EPB gets the credit - click the check mark on the left.